# Creating User Directories on server and adding permissions

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm now trying to add directories to a server for our new users automatically. I think I'm close to getting the script right but need a little help. If the user has the `company` attribute of `1480` then a folder is created in the `\\server\hs\sameaccountname` and if the attribute is `1479` then a folder is created in the `\\server-elem\samaccountname`. Plus the correct persmissions are assigned to this folder for the user.

```
#Search AD for HS Students
$hs = Get-ADUser -filter 'company -eq "1480"'
$path = "\\hs-ss\students\hs\"

forEach($user in $hs) {
    #Create user directory of Storage Server    
    New-Item -Path $path -Name $SamAccountName -ItemType "directory"
    $ACL = Get-ACL "$path\$SamAccountName"
    $ACL.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $true)
    $ACL.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("clasd\$SamAccountName", "Modify", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")))
    Set-Acl "$Path\$SamAccountName" $ACL
}
```

**Edit 1**

This is the error I get:

```
New-Item : Item with specified name \\hs-ss\students\hs\ already exists.
At C:\AD_Scripts\psscripts\user_create.ps1:76 char:1
+ New-Item -Path $path -Name $SamAccountName -ItemType "directory"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (\\hs-ss\students\hs\:String) [New-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

Exception calling "AddAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."
At C:\AD_Scripts\psscripts\user_create.ps1:79 char:1
+ $ACL.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRul ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdentityNotMappedException
```

**Edit 2**

Getting closer because the folder gets created but the permissions do not get added.

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                                             
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                                             
d----        11/15/2016   3:26 PM            111111                                                                                                                                           
Get-ACL : Cannot find path '\\hs-ss\students\hs\CN=Test student1,OU=Students,OU=Users,OU=HS,DC=clasd,DC=net.' because it does not exist.
At C:\AD_Scripts\psscripts\user_create.ps1:80 char:8
+ $ACL = Get-ACL "$path\$user.$SamAccountName"
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Acl], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetAcl_PathNotFound_Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\AD_Scripts\psscripts\user_create.ps1:81 char:1
+ $ACL.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$true)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\AD_Scripts\psscripts\user_create.ps1:82 char:1
+ $ACL.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRul ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Set-Acl : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'AclObject' because it is null.
At C:\AD_Scripts\psscripts\user_create.ps1:83 char:39
+ Set-Acl "$Path\$user.$SamAccountName" $ACL
+                                       ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Acl], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

Code:

```
#Search AD for HS Students

$hs = Get-ADUser -filter 'company -eq "1480"'
$path = "\\hs-ss\students\hs"
forEach($user in $hs)
{

#$samaccount = $user.SamAccountName


#Create user directory of Storage Server

New-Item -Path $path -Name $($User.SamAccountName) -ItemType "directory" | Out-Null
$ACL = Get-ACL "$path\$user.$SamAccountName"
$ACL.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$true)
$ACL.AddAccessRule((New-Object     System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("clasd\$user.$SamAccountName","Modify", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")))
Set-Acl "$Path\$user.$SamAccountName" $ACL
}
```

Comment: so what doesnt work?

Comment: $SamAccountName is this not empty? judging by the first error looks like it is.

Comment: when I do a Get-ADUser it returns a user, so samaccountname is not empty. Powershell is all new for me, so I'm learning as I go.

Comment: well, i don't think it is, since you need to call $user.samaccountname, so it would look like this: ``New-Item -Path $path -Name $($user.SamAccountName) -ItemType "directory"``

Comment: @JustinMerwin aren't you missing `$samaccountname = $user.SamAccountName` at the top of the foreach loop?

Comment: You don't need to manually create the folder or setup permissions if you're using folder redirection or home folders. If you've got the permissions setup correctly on the file server then AD will take care of it all for you: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/06/30/automatic-creation-of-user-folders-for-home-roaming-profile-and-redirected-folders/

Answer (score 0):

It definitely looks like you're trying to create the \hs folder again because the $SamAccountName attribute is blank.

Try adding more output if you're having issues:

```
#Search AD for HS Students
$hs = Get-ADUser -Filter 'Company -eq "1480"'
$path = "\\hs-ss\students\hs\"

forEach($user in $hs)
{
    $UserDirectory = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath $User.SamAccountName

    if ( Test-Path -Path $UserDirectory )
    {
        'Directory "{0}" already exists.' -f $UserDirectory | Write-Error
    }
    else 
    {
        try {
            'Creating directory for "{0}" at "{1}".' -f @($User.SamAccountName,$UserDirectory) | Write-Verbose
            New-Item $UserDirectory -ItemType Directory -Force
        } catch {
            throw
        }

        try {
            'Obtaining Acl of "{0}".' -f $UserDirectory | Write-Verbose
            $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $UserDirectory
        } catch {
            throw
        }

        try {
            'Adding Acl permissions on "{0}".' -f $UserDirectory | Write-Verbose
            $Acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$true)
            $AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("clasd\$SamAccountName","Modify", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
            $Acl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
        } catch {
            throw
        }

        try {
            'Setting Acl on "{0}".' -f $UserDirectory | Write-Verbose
            Set-Acl -Path $UserDirectory -AclObject $Acl
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }
}
```